Must pcntl_signal_dispatch always be used for signal handling?
I have a PHP script (executed via php script.php) which must be able to handle graceful shutdowns when receiving a SIGTERM signal.
For that I want to use pcntl_signal. Some experimentation showed me that pcntl_signal_dispatch must be used to ensure signal handlers will actually handle any pending OS signals.
What is confusing to me:

The documentation for pcntl_signal does not mention any usage of pcntl_signal_dispatch by any means.
The documentation for pcntl_signal_dispatch simply states that it will signal handlers.
My local testing always required me to call pcntl_signal_dispatch, otherwise my signal handlers were never picked up.

Is the usage of pcntl_signal_dispatch mandatory for signal handlers to be called? Or are there scenarios where signal handlers are automatically called by the PHP runtime?
This is the minimal reproducable example for what I am describing:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

function handleSignal(int $signo): void
{
    echo "Got signal: $signo\n";
}

pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'handleSignal');
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'handleSignal');

while (true) {
    // Assume that this program will receive a SIGTERM signal,
    // Locally you can simply do that via using htop to kill the process.

    sleep(1);

    // Remove this line an the script will not get any signals:
    pcntl_signal_dispatch();
}


I added an example which you may want to look at. Should clarify my question.

Please read the example properly. I am using tools like htop to send the signal. That is because this CLI script will be spawned as child process of a larger application.

The pcntl_signal_dispatch() function calls the signal handlers installed by pcntl_signal() for each pending signal. answers your question. So you can decide when the handlers should react. I was wrong in my first comment, so I deleted to avoid confusion.

The quick answer is: yes.

After your feedback I found some bug threads, some documentation and came to the conclusion that my confusion primarily stems from me having the wrong perspective. Using other languages I expected signal handling to be more "automatic". I tried to summarize this as answer.

As was commented on my question the simple answer seems to be: Yes - If you want to handle incoming OS signals in a plain PHP script, invoked like this php your-script.php, then you must not only define signal handlers via pcntl_signal, you will also have to invoke pcntl_signal_dispatch at least once for signals to be forwarded to your handlers.
I'd like to add some context for those programmers who are not primarily used to PHP but similar languages like JS or Go. When using PHP you must keep in mind its history and the primary use cases of it. The introduction to the pcntl extension reads:

Process Control should not be enabled within a web server environment and unexpected results may happen if any Process Control functions are used within a web server environment.

Reading this, I realized I was thinking wrong about the pcntl extension. My exception was, coming from other languages, that if I define a signal handler, it must automatically be invoked given any signals.
But thinking from the perspective of most PHP driven web applications, would that make sense? If you were to write a small PHP application and host it with some PHP web hosting platform, they would surely not want you to react to any OS signals since the web server (Apache, NGINX usw.) is the component responsible for that.
